# What is the difference between Google Apps Scripts and Gadgets in Google Sites

Tags: google-gadget, google-apps-script

I am getting familiar with Google Sites. What I want is, building a Site front-end for a Google Spreadsheet.

I want to Display data from the Spreadsheet in the Google Site, later maybe some graphics as well. To my knowledge there are two ways to accomplish this, Apps Scripts and Gadgets. Building a Gadget seemed much more easy in the beginning, however gives me some trouble. After reading more about Apps Scripts I finally found a way to access the Spreadsheet and display data.

But reading a lot of google documentation, I wonder what really is the difference? In what cases should one use Gadgets and in what case Apps Scripts?

Maybe I am just a little overwhelmed but it would be nice to get some feedback from experiences developers in that field!

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gadget is XML code containing HTML inside 
which means gadget is text.

Google Apps Script is kinda JavaScript
which means GAS is code.

Might be the main difference.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script is javascript, but run in server side. So it is not client side javascript like javascript Gadget or any HTML.

Google Apps Script use GWT, which generate client side Javascript.